# mathematical relationship between height of drop and horizontal splash distance

Tags: experimental-physics

I was just curious as I am still quite confused, if we vary the height of the ball when dropping it in a pool of water, is there a way to establish some mathematical relationship between the height of the mass dropped in to the pool of liquid and how far the splash will reach horizontally?

I understand from threads here how high the water will splash when dropped at some initial height, but I cannot seem or find any research done on the actual relationship between drop height and horizontal distance of the splashed liquid.

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Perhaps the angles of the faces of the object will have a marked effect.

Comment: But do I have to measure these angles? The only way I can imagine doing this is filming the splash and measuring from the video clip itself.

Comment: If a cube hits flat face parallel tothe water surface, or edge or point then what do you think will happen? A diver can enter water with little disturbance but the same diver can do a water bomb as well...